# How to write a hardcoded string value inside EL expression #{ } in JSF?

Tags: string, jsf, el

I am trying to do the following:

```
rendered="#{billBean.company.equals("something")}"
```

But the problem is I cannot write `"something"` inside `#{}`. It causes the below XML parsing error:

> Element type "h:commandLink" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quote (') to refer to a plain `String` inside EL:

```
rendered="#{billBean.company.equals('something')}"
```